# How to get actual value of text box from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox in HTML page like this

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="rangestarttxtField" name="rangestarttxtField" />
```

if I write something in textbox and try to get its value from javascript like this

```
$("#rangestarttxtField").val();
```

it is returning 0 instead of written value. How can I get the user written value without removing value="0" from markup?

Answer (score 5):

try something like this and see what you get:

```
$("#rangestarttxtField").bind('change', function(){
    console.log($("#rangestarttxtField").val(););
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work fine for me. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/S6SpZ/

```
alert($("#rangestarttxtField").val());

$("#rangestarttxtField").blur(function(){
    alert($("#rangestarttxtField").val());
});
```

First I'm alerting the initial value of the box. Then in the `blur` event I do the same again. You can see that it returns the user entered value and not the initial value as specified in the html `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably having it alert or log the initial value, but really what you want to do is bind the alert to an event like a button click or a change event.

Something like this should work for you:

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="rangestarttxtField" name="rangestarttxtField" />
<input type="submit" value="Get Value!" id="submitbutton" />


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function(){
       alert($('#rangestarttxtField').val());    
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3RdHf/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method that I use

```
var somevariable = document.getElementById("elementName").value;
```

Hope this helps